# Is there a way to have a system generated report of list of DBA in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security

I'm an auditor, and I want to ask if there is a list of system generated report of DBA users in SQL Server? Per my audit client, there is no way to generate it.

However, I'm thinking that this is a data also in which you can just generate to the SQL Server databases. I just want to validate that the list of DBAs is restricted to DBA of our company for legitimate business need and security purpose.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the information you are trying to collect? example: login names, host names, application names, last connection dates, etc? Or are you just looking for a list of logins on an instance?

Comment: I'm just looking for a extracted list of DBA in SQL Server. Just a login names will do.

Comment: Do you mean logins with sysadmin access? or that belong to a server role?

Comment: List of Database Administrator, I'm sorry I'm not really a technical person.

Comment: Database Administrator is a profession or a position - it's not a role or something on SQL server. So, if you need an answer, you should explain what `Database Administrator` means.

Comment: You should express what you want in terms of controls you want to audit.  When you ask specific questions (who is sysadmin) you get specific answers.  Ask "who can do X" and you will get more information.  Who is sysadmin is just one, but you probably also want to know who is security admin and who has db_owner access into the relevant databases.  These are high level permissions.  Then you would want to know which of those users is a login (password controlled by SQL) and which are windows authentication (password controlled by domain).  I've played the audit game from both sides...

Comment: To echo @JonathanFite's comment, your security controls should dictate what you need to audit.  Are these being driving by compliance standards or just internal standards?  If so, what standards are you trying to be compliant against (e.g. [SOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarbanes%E2%80%93Oxley_Act), [PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard), [NIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_Cybersecurity_Framework), etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This gives the list of users/logins/groups that have sysdba which sounds like your "Database Administrator" role.  This is not all logins, just the ones with the most powerful role.

```
USE master
GO

SELECT  p.name AS [loginname] ,
        CASE
        WHEN p.is_disabled = 1
        THEN 'LOCKED'
        ELSE 'OPEN'
        END as 'Account Status'
FROM    sys.server_principals p
        JOIN sys.syslogins s ON p.sid = s.sid
WHERE   p.type_desc IN ('SQL_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP')
        -- Logins that are not process logins
        AND p.name NOT LIKE '##%'
        -- Logins that are sysadmins
        AND s.sysadmin = 1
GO
```

Or you may prefer this query that shows who has the privileged roles on the database.  As a comment indicates if you want to focus on what a login can do you would include the securityadmin role as users with this role can elevate their privileges.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) for the documentation.  If there is poor access control you never know what you will find...

```
select * from sys.syslogins
go
select * from sys.sql_logins 
go
sp_helprolemember 'db_securityadmin'
go
sp_helprolemember 'db_owner'
go
sp_helprolemember 'db_accessadmin'
go
sp_helpsrvrolemember 'sysadmin'
go
sp_helpsrvrolemember 'serveradmin'
go
sp_helpsrvrolemember 'securityadmin'
go
```

Comment: I would add a check for securityadmin since they can elevate their own permissions if needed.